# How can I with Ruby check if SHA1 username, password and verifier/salt is correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, passwords, sha1

I have a username, password and this verifier, salt. How can I check with Ruby that it's correct?

The docs/instructions I'm following is this:
https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/account

My code atm looks like this:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
 self.table_name = "account"
 def self.check_username_password(username, password)
  account = Account.find_by(username: username)
  h1 = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(username.uppercase + password.uppercase)
  h2 = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest( account.salt + ..... )
  h2 == account.verifier
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs you link to describe the algorithm to calculate the verifier as:

> #### verifier
>
> verifier is derived from salt, as well as the user's username (all
> uppercase) and their password (all uppercase).
>
> To obtain the verifier you need to calculate:
>
> Calculate h1 = SHA1("USERNAME:PASSWORD"), substituting the user's
> username and password converted to uppercase.
>
> Calculate h2 = SHA1(salt || h1), where || is concatenation (the .
> operator in PHP).
>
> NOTE: Both salt and h1 are binary, not hexadecimal strings!
>
> Treat h2 as an integer in little-endian order (the first byte is the
> least significant).
>
> Calculate (g ^ h2) % N.
>
> NOTE: g and N are parameters, which are fixed in the WoW
> implementation.
>
> g = 7
>
> N = 0x894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7
>
> Convert the result back to a byte array in little-endian order.

Based on the links to sample implementations, this appears to be the verifier from SRP6, which you might be able to use this gem for: https://github.com/grempe/sirp. However, it doesn't line up exactly with the docs, and I think this might be interesting, so I'll try to work through it anyway.

First, you've got a start on finding `h1` and `h2`, but as the NOTE says, `Both salt and h1 are binary, not hexadecimal strings!`. So, you'll want to replace `hexdigest` with `digest`. Also, the uppercase method in Ruby is `upcase` and you'll need to put a colon between the two:

```
h1 = Digest::SHA1.digest("#{username.upcase}:#{password.upcase}")
h2 = Digest::SHA1.digest(account.salt + h1)
```

Next, it says to turn h2 into an integer as if it was stored in little-endian. Remember that integers are stored as sequences of bytes, each byte being 8 bits; so a 32-bit integer is 4 bytes. Endianness describes if the first byte maps to the first 8 bits or the last 8 bits of the number. Here, the comment makes it clear it'll be the last. Now, SHA1 produces a 20-byte hash, so we'll use `unpack` method plus the `H` directive (which matches each hex byte) to get it all out.

```
h2_int = h2.reverse.unpack("H*").first.to_i(16)
```

Lastly, we do some math with the given constants and convert it back to a string. The `^ %` construction must be modular exponentiation, which you can do in Ruby 2.5+ with just `Integer#pow`, or in Ruby 2.4 below with openssl's `mod_exp`:

```
g = 7
n = 0x894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7

verifier_int = g.pow(h2_int, n)

# ruby 2.4 or below:
#
# require 'openssl'
# verifier_int = g.to_bn.mod_exp(h2_int, n).to_i

verifier = [verifier_int.to_s(16)].pack('H*').reverse
```

Put that all together:

```
h1 = Digest::SHA1.digest("#{username.upcase}:#{password.upcase}")
h2 = Digest::SHA1.digest(account.salt + h1)

h2_int = h2.reverse.unpack("H*").first.to_i(16)

g = 7
n = 0x894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7

verifier_int = g.pow(h2_int, n)

# ruby 2.4 or below:
#
# require 'openssl'
# verifier_int = g.to_bn.mod_exp(h2_int, n).to_i

verifier = [verifier_int.to_s(16)].pack('H*').reverse
```

With this code, I was able to verify that for the values:

```
username = "testaccount"
password = "testaccount"
account.salt = "\xB1V\x940(|\x0F\xA0\xD6|\x7F\x86\xADO'\x82':(\xCCW\xA0\x85\xE1\xB2\xE20\x1A|3g\x1C" # [0xb1569430287c0fa0d67c7f86ad4f2782273a28cc57a085e1b2e2301a7c33671c.to_s(16)].unpack('H*')
```

The produced verifier matches the expected verifier of:

```
"\xB6\x95\xFF\xEB\x8E\xA76u\x8F\xFB\x0F:\xE34M\t\xC0?\xE8\xD2\xF1\xD1\x8C\x058P\x8F\xCDyQ H"
```

### In Rails

After testing this out, the following code works for me. Note that I've casted the encoding of salt to ascii-8bit here, instead of verifier to utf-8, but it doesn't change the result. However, for the final comparison, the encodings *do* need to be the same.

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  def verify(password)
    h1 = Digest::SHA1.digest("#{username.upcase}:#{password.upcase}")
    h2 = Digest::SHA1.digest(salt.force_encoding('ascii-8bit') + h1)

    h2_int = h2.reverse.unpack("H*").first.to_i(16)

    g = 7
    n = 0x894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7

    verifier_int = g.pow(h2_int, n)
    verifier = [verifier_int.to_s(16)].pack('H*').reverse

    verifier == self.verifier
  end
end
```

Comment: Getting this error `dynamic constant assignment
    N = 0x894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B...` Will add another comment later today with an example username and pw verifier.

Comment: I created an example account in the DB. This is the info: `username: testaccount, password: testaccount. And in the DB it's stored like this: "username: testaccount", "salt: ±V”0(| Ö|†­O'‚':(ÌW …á²â0|3g", "verifier: ¶•ÿëŽ§6uû:ã4M    À?èÒñÑŒ8PÍyQ H"` all without the " symbol.

Comment: @EmilStåhlMyllyaho the constant error is fixed (just had to lowercase the "N" to "n'). I'm not sure if I'm decoding the example values of salt and verifier from your comment accurately, could you share them in base64? E.g. `require 'base64'; Base64.encode64(salt)`

Comment: @EmilStåhlMyllyaho I'm able to decode those, thanks, but my code is producing a different verifier. I'm wondering if something may be off in the documentation, though, because the verifier you have there is a 53-byte string, but the expression `(g ^ h2) % N` can only produce a value smaller than N and N is only 31 bytes. The sample code from the docs also notes that verifier should be 32 bytes. How were you able to create the example account? Can you trace the code that creates the verifier on the way in?

Comment: @PeterNubel I think the salt and verifier info I posted in an earlier comment was wrong. The SQL Client I was using was showing bytes I think. Now when I've exported it into a single sql file, salt and verifier looks like this instead: `username: testaccount, password: testaccount, salt: 0xb1569430287c0fa0d67c7f86ad4f2782273a28cc57a085e1b2e2301a7c33671c, verifier: 0xb695ffeb8ea736758ffb0f3ae3344d09c03fe8d2f1d18c0538508fcd79512048` Is that helpful for u? Do u still need me to encode it to base64?

Comment: @EmilStåhlMyllyaho thanks, with those values, I'm able to produce the same result, no need for the alternate versions. I'll edit the answer with the final code.

Comment: @PeterNubel I'm still getting errors trying to run it with your salt. `incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)`. If I use a different salt, like salt = 'abc' then it works for me.

Comment: @EmilStåhlMyllyaho try `h2 = Digest::SHA1.digest(account.salt.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT') + h1)` -- I'm not positive if it will work correctly, but it's worth a shot as a start.

Comment: @PeterNubel In Ruby console it now produces the exact same verifier that I posted before: `verifier: ¶•ÿëŽ§6uû:ã4M    À?èÒñÑŒ8PÍyQ H`. But when I run the same code in rails console I'm getting this, which seems to be wrong? It seems to be same encoding, but different from what you posted? verifier: `"\x97\x9C\xDBu\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"`

Comment: @EmilStåhlMyllyaho Probably encoding issues... what version of Ruby and Rails are you using, so I can emulate the environment appropriately?

Comment: @PeterNubel I'm using ruby 2.7.1 and rails 7.0.1. I really appreciate you helping me out, thank you so much.

Comment: @EmilStåhlMyllyaho in the same environment, I was able to get it to work. I didn't really change anything but I have included the code of the model in the answer above -- hopefully that helps you out!